How do I model an extract element between items in a list using JAXB?
I have the following annotations on a class to generate UUIDs as primary keys. I am getting the exception below when I try to persist a entity. I am using EclipseLink. Any idea how to resolve this.
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
private UUID uuid;

Exception Description: The instance variable [uuid] in the object [za.co.temp.planet.module.innovation.domain.Innovation] is inaccessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor (in module eclipselink) cannot access a member of class za.co.temp.planet.module.innovation.domain.Innovation (in module za.co.temp.planet) with modifiers "private"
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[uuid-->INNOVATION.UUID]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(za.co.temp.planet.module.innovation.domain.Innovation --> [DatabaseTable(INNOVATION)])

I m trying to persist a entity using JPA.
